# How to move a CloudFormation StackSet to a different account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have some CloudFormation StackSet created in account A and it creates a resource in account 1. Now we want to move the stackset from account A to a different account (account B). The deployed resources should remain in account 1 and can't be redeployed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Not sure what issue you have here? If you already have a Cloudformation Template used to create this, and you want resources that are already created to remain in Account A, (and new ones created in Account B), why not just deploy a new Stack in Account B? Or I misinterpreted something in your question?

Comment: True, but they have created S3 buckets over a lot of accounts, I don't want to move the content, remove the buckets, recreate them and move the content back for all of them.

Comment: Not sure what you would like to do with those S3 buckets? I mean, it's not possible to migrate them to another account. That would require re-creation and re-uploading of the data...

Comment: The resources aren't moving. They're staying in the same account they're in (account 1). But they were created by a CloudFormation StackSet originating in a second account (account A) that is now moving to a third account (account B). This could happen if you move an account between payer organizations, for instance.